# How to get access to authenticated, logged in user in vue.js and django rest framework

Tags: django, vue.js, authentication, django-rest-framework

I want to get access to authenticated, currently logged in user, eg. to username and id, and to put it in to the form by default when I'm using POST method.
My login component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'LoginForm',
  components: {

  },
  data(){
      return{
          username: '',
          password: '',
          token: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || null,
      }
  },
  methods: {
      login(){
          axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/',{
              username: this.username,
              password: this.password,
          })
          .then(resp => {
              this.token = resp.data.token;
              localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.data.token)
              this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
              })
          .catch(err => {
              localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
          })
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you have an endpoint that returns the user profile, something like: `http://127.0.0.1/users/me`?

Comment: I have global users endpoint - http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/

Comment: Does it return the user info after the user login? What package are you using for auth, only DRF?

Comment: Yes, only Django Rest Framework. When I ```console.log(resp)``` I have all data, include username, password and token.

Comment: OK, so if you have all the data you are in home. BTW, you can't put the data in the form without doing the POST. One way to have some default in the form is to hardcode it.